# Turn off delete pixels

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing

I have one important question.

When I drawing in Photoshop, I sometimes go beyond the work area and pixel which was been outside is removed... May I can this turn off and feel himself free?

[image: After draw pixels left the work area]

[image: And removed...]

Answer (score 0):

Not the free making solution, but a workaround that can prevent losing a stroke or two.

Have 2 layers. The work layer for the drawing and a guard layer with a black solid frame on it:

[image]

The black frame can be made for example by making a rectangular selection, inverting the selection and filling with black.

Paint enthusistically to the work layer:

[image]

Here quite soon you might have noticed that there's no new line at the right end altough the brush moves. You have time to stop before losing anything.

Goto Image  > Canvas size and make the canvas bigger:

[image]

Also drag the frame in the guard layer bigger and now you have new space to continue.

[image]

If this look out a bad joke, then use Illustrator or Inkscape. There the canvas size is independent of the drawing size.

Comment: Hey man=) It's too bad idea, because I work with mobile resolution, and I can't change my resolution=( But I found only one solution - to make other  big layer and to work in there...